# Simple form for Model Admin in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

By default, Model Admin is used to manage a model/s, and if the model is skipped, the result is an error.

```
/* private static $managed_models = array(
    'OneModel'
); */
```

I want to display a simple form (Textfield for a password and an action button) first, then if the password is correct, it should go the to a the gridfield.

I tried to change the getCMSfields inside the model, but the field is visible only if i click on one of the records from the gridfield:

```
public function getCMSfields(){
    $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root', $login = Tab::create('Authorise', 
        TextField::create('Password')
    )));
    return $fields;
}
```

Edit:

This secondary password it's the key to decrypt the data for that DataObject, is not a regular login, so it's an additional security method to keep safe some sensitive data.

Comment: I suggest against having a log in form inside the CMS. I suggest using the SilverStripe authentication and permission features to control if a user can view this section instead. Is there a reason to use an extra log in form inside the CMS rather than SilverStripe's security features?

Comment: Absolutely! If a user has permission to view or edit a specific DataObject, why should he login again? You can overwrite the can* methods like canCreate(), canView(), canEdit() and canDelete() in your Model and use PermissionProvider to add global permissions to a Group of Members. See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/model/permissions/ and https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/security/permissions/

Comment: I fully agree with the above - the permissions should decide what a user can or cannot see - I wouldn't create a login within system that already has a login

Comment: I'm afraid i was wrong understood. Data, that comes from this dataObject are stored in a second database, that are encrypted, and this password/key is compared with key for encryption which is stored somewhere on the server. So this is not a login. is just an additional securty method in order to keep safe the sensitive data.

Comment: I still don't see the reason to use an extra password form inside the CMS.  Why not just set up permissions in the CMS allowing certain users to have access to the data, and not for other users ? Making the user enter a second password screen is a crap user experience and it doesn't make the system any more secure.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, for those in similar situation. Instead of using ModelAdmin, we can use LeftAndMain. so the code will be:

```
class Applications extends LeftAndMain {
    static $url_segment = 'applications';
    static $menu_title = 'Applications';
    static $url_rule = '$Action/$ID';

    public function init(){
        parent::init();
    }

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'login'
    );

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextField::create('Password', ' Password')
        );
        $actions = new FieldList(new FormAction('applicationPassword'));
        return new Form($this, "EditForm", $fields, $actions);
    }

    public function applicationPassword($data, Form $form){
        $pass = $data['Password'];
        $form->sessionMessage('Password submited for testing : '.$pass, 'success');
         return $this->redirect('login');
    }

     public function login(){
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

One more need would be, after validation, in the nest step to show the regular gridfield with the model records, but when i succed, i will return with an answer as well.